# Webpack build error after adding TailwindCSS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, tailwind-css

I added TailwindCSS to my Vue2 project that is compiled using Webpack 5. When I run `webpack --mode production` on my local environment it works fine. But when I commit it and run it through Bitbucket Pipelines it gives the following error for every css/scss/inline style I have in the project:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css (./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js??clonedRuleSet-3[0].rules[0].use[1]!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-3[0].rules[0].use[2]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-3[0].rules[0].use[4]!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value).slice(...).reverse(...).flatMap is not a function
    at Object.getAllConfigs [as default] (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/util/getAllConfigs.js:17:26)
    at Object.resolveConfig [as default] (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/public/resolve-config.js:14:60)
    at getTailwindConfig (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/lib/setupTrackingContext.js:65:52)
    at /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/lib/setupTrackingContext.js:124:92
    at /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/processTailwindFeatures.js:43:11
    at plugins (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/index.js:20:104)
    at LazyResult.runOnRoot (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:339:16)
    at LazyResult.runAsync (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:393:26)
    at LazyResult.async (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:221:30)
    at LazyResult.then (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:206:17)
    at processResult (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:758:19)
    at runLoaders (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:860:5)
    at /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:399:11
    at /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:251:18
    at context.callback (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
    at Object.loader (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/index.js:142:7)
 @ ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css 2:12-313 9:17-24 13:15-29
 @ ./src/main.js 9:0-46
```

It appears to be doing a `getTailwindConfig` call in the postcss-loader/mini-css-extract-plugin.

My scss/css rule in my webpack.config.js:

```
    {
      test: /\.s?css$/,
      use: [
        "style-loader",
        {
          loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          options: {
            esModule: false,
          },
        },
        {
          loader: "css-loader",
          options: {
            importLoaders: 1,
          },
        },
        {
          loader: "postcss-loader",
        },
        {
          loader: "sass-loader",
          options: {
            implementation: require("dart-sass"),
          },
        },
      ],
    },
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong, and why it only occurs on Bitbucket Pipelines and not on my local machine?

Comment: What version of NodeJS is bitbucket using?

Comment: Ahh, it was on node 10. I upgraded it and now the build is passing. Thanks a lot!